# Error Message: error: unknown type name ‘int8_t’

Tags: c, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, gcc

Environment:
64-bit Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    printf("hello world");
}
```

Terminal output:

```
Localhost_8080 says: make hello
cc     hello.c   -o hello
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include/stdint.h:9,
                 from /usr/include/bits/environ.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/bits/alltypes.h:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/stdio.h:22,
                 from hello.c:1:
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:22:9: error: unknown type name ‘int8_t’
   22 | typedef int8_t int_fast8_t;
      |         ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:23:9: error: unknown type name ‘int64_t’
   23 | typedef int64_t int_fast64_t;
      |         ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:25:9: error: unknown type name ‘int8_t’
   25 | typedef int8_t  int_least8_t;
      |         ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:26:9: error: unknown type name ‘int16_t’
   26 | typedef int16_t int_least16_t;
      |         ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:27:9: error: unknown type name ‘int32_t’
   27 | typedef int32_t int_least32_t;
      |         ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:28:9: error: unknown type name ‘int64_t’
   28 | typedef int64_t int_least64_t;
      |         ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:30:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint8_t’
   30 | typedef uint8_t uint_fast8_t;
      |         ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:31:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
   31 | typedef uint64_t uint_fast64_t;
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:33:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint8_t’
   33 | typedef uint8_t  uint_least8_t;
      |         ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:34:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint16_t’
   34 | typedef uint16_t uint_least16_t;
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:35:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint32_t’
   35 | typedef uint32_t uint_least32_t;
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:36:9: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
   36 | typedef uint64_t uint_least64_t;
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdint.h:95:10: fatal error: bits/stdint.h: No such file or directory
   95 | #include <bits/stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: hello] Error 1
```

Debugging message from Problems:

```
[{
    "resource": "/home/MYSELF/Documents/My Codes (exp Localhost)/VS/hello.c",
    "owner": "C/C++: IntelliSense",
    "code": "1696",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "cannot open source file \"bits/stdint.h\" (dependency of \"stdio.h\")",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 19
}]

[{
    "resource": "/usr/local/include/stdint.h",
    "owner": "cpptools",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "unknown type name ‘int8_t’",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 22,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 22,
    "endColumn": 9
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/include/stdint.h",
    "owner": "cpptools",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "unknown type name ‘int64_t’",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 23,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 23,
    "endColumn": 9
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/include/stdint.h",
    "owner": "cpptools",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "unknown type name ‘int8_t’",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 25,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 25,
    "endColumn": 9
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/include/stdint.h",
    "owner": "cpptools",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "unknown type name ‘int16_t’",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 26,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 26,
    "endColumn": 9
},{
    "resource": "/usr/local/include/stdint.h",
    "owner": "cpptools",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "unknown type name ‘int32_t’",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 27,
    "startColumn": 9,
    "endLineNumber": 27,
    "endColumn": 9
}]
```

VS configuration for Include Path:
`/usr/include/**`

I've installed the C/C++ extensions in Visual Studio Code.

I've done `sudo apt-get install build-essential` (0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 8 not to upgrade), and manually downloaded all files from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/tesseract/+/refs/heads/main/include into `/usr/include/bits/` as I previously saw one error message saying `fatal error: bits/alltypes.h: No such file or directory`.

It seems that the more C header files I install, the more error messages about something missing will appear. I wonder if something is wrong with my setup?

Comment: I want to give you lots of credits for actually sticking to Hello world before you do anything more complicated. More people should do that.

Comment: If you are using those types you must say `#include <stdint.h>` in your .c code file.  Of course, it's a bit puzzling because I don't see where you are using those types ( `uint32_t` and others).

Comment: @gregspears That header `stdint.h` is exactly where the error is reported. There seems to be some underlying target definition missing.

Comment: sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib ?

Comment: What is in `/usr/local/include/stdint.h`?  Where did it come from?  `/usr/local/include` should not be where `stdint.h` comes from unless you *really* know what you're doing with your system.

Comment: *and manually downloaded all files from...* You brought a lot of uncontrolled garbage to your Ubuntu. Don't know how you now can move forward with such bad experience. Maybe completely reinstall Ubuntu and forget `sudo`. Use the system package manager and don't write any file outside the home directory.